# Firebase automatically signs out from the user session on iOS app

Tags: ios, firebase-authentication

I am struggling with Firebase authentication in my app.  I have enabled the database persistence using:

```
[FIRDatabase database].persistenceEnabled = YES;
```

After the user logs in (email/password authentication), I am expecting the session to remain active until I explicitly `signout:`.  To handle the changes in authorization, I set up the following (with some debugging code to check out the behavior based on the application state changes):

```
[[FIRAuth auth] addAuthStateDidChangeListener:^(FIRAuth * _Nonnull auth, FIRUser * _Nullable user) {
    if (user != nil) {
        ZLog(YES, @"Signed in %@\n\n\n>>>>\n\n\n", user.uid);
        [user getTokenWithCompletion:^(NSString * _Nullable token, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            ZLog(NO, @"Token %@\n\n\n####\n\n\n", token);
        }];
    } else {
        ZLog(YES, @"Not Signed In\n\n\n>>>>\n\n\n");
        FIRUser *user = [[FIRAuth auth] currentUser];
        ZLog(YES, @"The user is %@", (user != nil) ? user : @"nil");
    }
}];
```

everything seems to be ok even after reinstalling the app from Xcode while debugging.  However as soon as the app goes in "Inactive state" (e.g. by pressing the Home button).  I get the "Sign out" in my listener block.  This does not happen if I just switch to another app when my app goes to "background" as observed by `applicationDidEnterBackground`.

What could be wrong? The documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities) suggests that the session should be saved across app restarts (which implies the cases like `applicationWillResignActive` and `applicationDidBecomeActive`, I assume).

I would not like to re-authenticate (with the safely saved email/password credentials) on every such change (and it would also defeat the 'offline' capabilities claim).  Or would the re-authentication also work in 'offline' mode?

Going crazy trying to solve this - any clues would be helpful!  Thx.

Comment: Ignoring the logging on app exit: when you restart the app, does it fire the auth state change *with* a user again?

Comment: If I restart the app, the auth state change shows no user (i.e. [[FIRAuth auth] currentUser] returns nil).  However, if I have the app open in a Debug session and I reinstall it while it was running, it shows the user session as Signed in.  This baffles me as I would assume that the app is 'killed' and restarted.

Comment: Hmmm.... I can't reproduce this. Just added this code to my app delegate `FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener() { (auth, user) in if (user != nil) { print("User is signed in") } else { print("User is not signed in") } }` and it just prints `User is signed in` twice when I start the app. Nothing is printed when I press the Home button, which is how it should work. Not sure what triggers it on your code.

Comment: Hi - In addition, when the device goes to sleep, the Auth state changes to "Signed out" as well.

Comment: Thanks, @FrankvanPuffelen.  I don't see any other places where I would set up any parameters (as in Firebase Console), so I am not sure what is causing the issue here.  Anything I should be watching in the GoogleService-Info.plist?  I don't see anything that would cause it (unless something that is needed is missing!) - I have enabled `LoggingEnabled` to help debug?  (Not sure how to use it though - Where is the log maintained?)

Comment: Another thought/question -  Will it matter if any `-observeEventType:withBlock:` on a database reference or query need to be dealt with, when the app is changing to one of the inactive states?  I do have active listeners and whether there is anything to be done about it.